# Notification when contact is modified in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, contacts

Contacts in the phone are displayed in my windows phone 7 app.
   My requirement is to update the contact in my app when it is changed from the outside. How can i get the notification of change in contact..?
Or what is the best way of updating contacts with good app performance.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get notification on contact changes. All you can do is to re-read contacts from time to time (for example on app launching).

Comment: But i need to maintain previous and changed contacts.